# rePlaykit returns RPRecordingErrorContentResize

Tags: ios, objective-c, microphone

I am developing for the `iphone 7`, under the operating system `ios12.0` I call this method,it returns the following Error:

```
Error Domain=com.apple.ReplayKit.RPRecordingErrorDomain Code=-5807

- (void)startRecordingWithMicrophoneEnabled:(BOOL)microphoneEnabled handler:(nullable void(^)(NSError * _Nullable error))handler API_DEPRECATED("Use microphoneEnabaled property", ios(9.0, 10.0));
```

Comment: how can i solve this error

Comment: startRecordingWithMicrophoneEnabled:  is deprecated use startCaptureWithHandler:completionHandler: you can see at  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/replaykit/rpscreenrecorder/2867291-startcapturewithhandler?language=objc